# Implementation of Friedman's algorithm of reconstructing simple polytopes

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, convex-geometry, convex-polytopes, linear-programming

In [Finding a Simple Polytope from Its Graph in Polynomial Time](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-008-9121-7), Friedman gave a polynomial time algorithm on reconstructing a simple polytope from its graph. Has this algorithm been actually implemented somewhere? For example, in SageMath, Polymake, or GAP.